# Why is my code only printing the first element in the array in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays

The resulting code only prints out the first element of the array in my Xcode, even though I pass it three words. Any reason why?

```
char str[100] = {0};

        NSLog(@"Please enter three words: ");
        scanf("%s", str);
        NSString *words = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: str];

        NSMutableArray *mutableWords = [[words componentsSeparatedByString: @" "] mutableCopy];

        NSLog(@"%@", mutableWords);
```

Comment: `NSLog("%d", [mutableWords count]);` should reveal the answer.

Comment: I suspected as such, is there a reason why the rest of the words are not getting passed into the array??

Comment: log your `str`, your `str` maybe wrong , I have instead you `str` of `"adaf fdsf sdf"` and its log is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

This will read the entire line into `str`.

---

The easiest way to get rid of the `'\n'` character left as the last index of your array is to simple change how you're splitting your array:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableWords = [[words componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Please excuse me, I'm coming from the Ruby world, so this setup strikes me as very odd, upon first impression. Is it not readily possible to read an entire string into a variable, and then split that into an array delimited by single-spaces, without jumping through hoops?

Comment: You can.  I just updated answer.  I was looking for the solution to read the entire line.  I don't do a whole lot of reading from console, since 99% of my Obj-C programming is GUI-based.

Comment: It says _Too few arguments to call, expected 3, have 2_

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer Nevermind `getline`, you can just use the `fgets` method I put there.

Comment: it gives me: _Incompatible pointer types passing 'char[3]' to parameter of type 'size_t'(aka unsigned long *)_, that message was for the getline

Comment: `getline` or `fgets`?

Comment: Sorry, I had entered in that last one right after your last message. Could you update your answer with fgets?

Comment: Answer has `fgets` in it currently.

Comment: Nice, getting there. Any idea how to chomp that /n?

Comment: I think `fgets` eats it and `getline` doesn't.  One of them leaves it in `stdin`, the other one will leave it as the last character in the string.

Comment: No, you were right on the money in your answer, I still have the newline at the last element in the array.

Comment: that gives me "" for the last element.

Comment: Oh... hmm.  Then I guess you can always just remove the last object, knowing it will always be an empty string if you built the array from splitting a string you got from `fgets` in this manner.

Comment: I borrowed this, it seems to work, albeit its kind of g:

`if (stream[strlen(stream) - 1] == '\n') {
  stream[strlen(stream) - 1] = '\0';
}`

Answer (score 0):

> s     Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next
>   pointer must be a
>          pointer to char, and the array must be large enough to accept all the sequence
>          and the terminating NUL character.  The input string stops at white space or at
>          the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

from man scanf.

I guess you just get the first word in the string in the first place.
By the way, using scanf this way is highly unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

because you are reading one word with `scanf("%s", str);`

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first
>   whitespace character found. A terminating null character is
>   automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

use [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read whole line

Comment: I see...so how do I read the entire contents that the user inputs??